# Find : $ \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}dx $

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

> Find:
>
> $$ \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}dx $$

My initial thoughts were to use a trigonometric substitution of $x=\tan(\theta)$ which implies that $ dx= \sec^2(\theta) d\theta$ this transforms our integral into

$$ \int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}dx = \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \frac{1}{1+(\tan(\theta))^{2015}} d\theta $$

But I'm having trouble evaluating it after.

I also tried a substitution of $y=\frac{1}{x}$ but that did not get me anywhere either.

Thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Try again $y=\frac{1}{x}$.

---

\begin{align}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}dx&=\int^1_0 \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}dx+\int^\infty_1 \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}dx\\
&=\int^1_0 \frac{1}{(1+x^{2015})(1+x^2)}dx+\int^1_0 \frac{y^{2015}}{(1+y^{2015})(1+y^2)}dy\\
&=?
\end{align}

Comment: Very bad to give the same hint as that which was answered in the duplicate.

Comment: @Rohan To be fair the duplicate was suggested *after* the answer was posted.

Comment: Yeah. I didn't know it's duplicate...

Answer (score 2):

You can use 
$$\int_a^bf(x) \, dx = \int_a^bf(a+b-x) \, dx$$
to get
$$I=\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \frac{1}{1+(\tan(\theta))^{2015}} d\theta=\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \frac{1}{1+(\cot(\theta))^{2015}} d\theta$$
Then 
\begin{align*}
2I & = \int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \frac{1}{1+(\tan(\theta))^{2015}} d\theta+\int^\frac{\pi}{2}_0 \frac{1}{1+(\cot(\theta))^{2015}} d\theta\\
2I & = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}1 \, d \theta
\end{align*}